# How can I generate a new Angular project that honors specified indention styles

Tags: angular-cli, lint

I've been an angular dev for a long time and it always bugs me that running `ng new` did not seem to provide a way to create a new project with a specified indentation type (tabs vs. spaces) or amount (2 vs. 4).

I'm starting a new Angular 7 project and from reading [related discussions on github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6272) it *seems* this problem has been fixed. Naturally, the solutions are convoluted and contradictory, and I'm clearly doing something wrong, because I can't get lintFix to run. When I run it manually it doesn't seem to do anything.

**Can someone please walk me through the steps to generate a new Angular project that honors specified indention styles** immediately after starting off with a brand new: `npm install -g @angular/cli` for Angular 7?

Answer (score 10):

In my case I wanted to change 2 spaces to 4, and running `ng lint --fix` did nothing, because tslint's indentation fixer does not alter the amount of indentation, just the type.

I was able to work around this immediately after running `ng new` by altering the tslint.json to add:

```
"indent": [
    true,
    "tabs",
    2
],
```

Then I ran `ng lint --fix` and all space indentations were fixed to tabs. Then I set the indentation back to what I really wanted:

```
"indent": [
    true,
    "spaces",
    4
],
```

...and ran `ng lint --fix` again. Now all existing indentation is correct. Of course any further Angular CLI generators will still use 2 spaces, so this is not a full solution, but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 4):

TSLint is dead. In Angular v10 and later you should use ESLint. [Angular-eslint](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint) to be more exact.

There is an option to migrate existing project. See their readme.

Adding indentation rule:

```
        "rules": {
            "indent": ["error", "tab"],
...
            "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
```

Note! Be careful to add it for *.ts only. So before `@angular-eslint/component-selector`. Indent rule will cause problems if you try to add it for HTML.

Generating a component and linting:

```
ng generate component components/todos
ng lint --fix
```

Answer (score 2):

With the latest in the Angular 8.2.1, I have been able to get this to work somewhat for tabs that are 4 spaces.  I set my tslint.json indent incorrectly, which is to be tabs, but with 2 spaces.

```
"indent": [
    true,
    "tabs",
    2
],
```

Now when I use the ng generate, the schematic does change the spacing to be tabs, and does create 2 tabs where it was needed.  Using an indent of tabs, with spacing of 4, the code that is just 2 spaced characters indent, does not have tab replacements.

I then have my .editorconfig set to have the indent style set to tabs, but to have the spacing for a tab to be 4 characters. This then looks proper in all my editors, as the underlying source code does have the proper tab stops created by the ng generate with the --lintFix flag.

```
indent_style = tabs
indent_size = 4
```

The text now is spaced properly in Visual Studio Code or other editors on the different platforms I use.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can run TS Lint fixors with your favorite indentation for that.